# How to create Python3 Asynchronous Web Requests with asyncio & aiohttp?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am struggling to wrap my head around the asyncio library. I thought you could simply define the sections of your code you want to run asynchronous, but in all the examples I have seen, people tend to define their main function as asynchronous. Here is the code that I have written:

```py
async def download_post(id, path):
    print(f"Begin downloading {id}")
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(f"{apiurl}item/{id}.json?print=pretty") as resp:
            json = await resp.json()
            content = await resp.text()
            print(f"Done downloading {id}")
            if json["type"] == "story":
                print(f"Begin writing to {id}.json")
                with open(os.path.join(path, f"{id}.json"), "w") as file:
                    file.write(content)
                    print(f"Done writing to {id}.json")

async def update_posts(path):
    myid = get_myid(path)
    if myid < maxid: # Database can be updated
        for id in range(myid+1, maxid):
            await download_post(id, path)
def main():
    if not os.path.exists(posts_dir):
        os.makedirs(posts_dir)
    path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), posts_dir)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(update_posts(path))
    loop.close()
    #domain_counts(path)

if __name__ ==  '__main__':
    main()
```

The key here is that `range(myid+1, maxid):` is very large, and `requests.get()` takes a relatively long time. However, after trying to switch from requests to aiohttp with asyncio, I am still getting responces one-by-one as shown in the output below

```
Begin downloading 1
Done downloading 1
Begin writing to 1.json
Done writing to 1.json
Begin downloading 2
Done downloading 2
Begin writing to 2.json
Done writing to 2.json
Begin downloading 3
Done downloading 3
Begin writing to 3.json
Done writing to 3.json
Begin downloading 4
Done downloading 4
Begin writing to 4.json
Done writing to 4.json
```

I thought about splitting the download and write to file code into different functions, but then I'm not sure whether both of those would have to be async as well. Also, I think I would have to make many of the variables start with `await`. These are the resources I have referencing:

1. [Easy parallel HTTP requests with Python and asyncio](https://skipperkongen.dk/2016/09/09/easy-parallel-http-requests-with-python-and-asyncio/)
2. [Intro to aiohttp](https://us-pycon-2019-tutorial.readthedocs.io/aiohttp_intro.html)
3. [Making Concurrent HTTP requests with Python AsyncIO](https://www.laac.dev/blog/concurrent-http-requests-python-asyncio/)

Does anyone have some good resources I good go over to better understand what I am doing wrong? I've noticed many examples use `asyncio.gather()`, but I don't really understand how it's used. Do I need to put `async` in-front of every function/`with` and `await` in-front of every variable?

Comment: You are calling `download_post` in a loop. You need to use something like `asyncio.gather` to let multiple invocations run at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of important things:

- Python interpreter GIL, runs on a single-thread; so technically you arent really running things in parallel
- But the catch is, most I/O operations 'hog' resources while your CPU during these periods is still idle. Thats where libraries like `asyncio` comes to your rescue.
- They try to ensure *minimal* CPU-idle-time, by running other tasks in your queue while major I/O operations are awaiting their results

In your case, `update_posts()` doesnt really seem like an async method in an ideal sense; because this method is technically only used to figure out which posts are to be *downloaded and written*

And since we are already discussing about download and writing, you can notice that you can actually make them run as independent tasks so ensure minimal downtime.

Here is how I might approach this:

```
import asyncio
from asyncio import Queue
import aiohttp
import os


async def generate_download_post_tasks(path, queue: Queue):
    myid = get_myid(path)
    if myid < maxid: # Database can be updated
        for id in range(myid+1, maxid):
            queue.put_nowait((id, path))


async def download_post_tasks(download_queue: Queue, write_queue: Queue):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        while True:
            download_request_id, path = await download_queue.get()
            async with session.get(f"{apiurl}item/{download_request_id}.json?print=pretty") as resp:
                json = await resp.json()
                content = await resp.text()
                print(f"Done downloading {download_request_id}")
                if json["type"] == "story":
                    write_queue.put_nowait((download_request_id, content, path))


async def write_post_tasks(write_queue: Queue):
    while True:
        post_id, post_content, path = await write_queue.get()
        print(f"Begin writing to {post_id}.json")
        with open(os.path.join(path, f"{post_id}.json"), "w") as file:
            file.write(post_content)
            print(f"Done writing to {post_id}.json")


async def async_main():
    if not os.path.exists(posts_dir):
        os.makedirs(posts_dir)
    path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), posts_dir)

    tasks = set()
    download_queue = Queue()
    write_queue = Queue()
    tasks.add(asyncio.create_task(generate_download_post_tasks(path=path, queue=download_queue)))
    tasks.add(asyncio.create_task(download_post_tasks(download_queue=download_queue, write_queue=write_queue)))
    tasks.add(asyncio.create_task(write_post_tasks(write_queue=write_queue)))

    wait_time = 100

    try:
        await asyncio.wait_for(asyncio.gather(*tasks), wait_time)
    except:
        # Catch errors
        print("End!!")
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(async_main())
```